Average Speed in one half of an elliptical orbit
I was wondering whether the average speed along one half of an elliptical orbit (say in a star planet system) had a closed form exact solution using Kepler's laws.
My approach was using the approximation for circumference of the ellipse, dividing by 2 and then dividing the entire thing by half the time period of an elliptical orbit. While this approach is straightforward, it only has an approximate answer.

If you have Mathematica software available, you can get the circumference of an ellipse easily in closed form via the 'Complete Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind' (EllipticE in Mathematica) . I quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind  :
For an ellipse with semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$ and eccentricity $e=\sqrt{1−b^2/a^2}$, the complete elliptic integral of the second kind $E(e)$ is equal to one quarter of the circumference $C$ of the ellipse measured in units of the semi-major axis $a$. In other words:
$$C = 4 a E ( e )$$
If you want the actual speed at each part of the orbit, then there is the very useful vis-viva equation
$$v^2 = GM \left({ 2 \over r} - {1 \over a}\right)$$
where $r$ is the distance between the two masses at the present location and $a$ the semi-major axis. It is probably more useful though to replace $r$ by the true anomaly $\phi$ (the polar angle of the position referred to the focus of the ellipse) by using the relationship
$$r=\frac{a\cdot (1-e^2)}{1+e\cdot \cos{\phi}}$$
This gives you only $v$ as a function of $\phi$ obviously. Trying to formulate this as a function of time (by making $\phi(t)$ a time dependent variable) gets very ugly mathematically and only allows approximate solutions.

Wikipedia mentions that the AGM algorithms for complete elliptic integrals converge very rapidly. There are related algorithms for the incomplete integrals. See Carlson (1994) https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.math/9409227 The complete integral of the 2nd kind gives you the ellipse perimeter, the incomplete integral is needed for general elliptical arcs.

It's my understanding that the perimeter of an ellipse, given by
$$
 \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm d\theta \sqrt{
a^2\cos^2\theta + b^2\sin^2\theta
},
$$
does not itself have a closed-form solution for nonzero $a\neq b$. I think this is related to the mathematical field of "elliptical integrals," which don't have analytical solutions, but I don't know the details.
Since speed is distance over time, and you don't have a closed-form expression for the total distance over any interval, you can't have a closed-form expression for the speed over any interval, either.

If I may add, we do have a closed form equation for the orbital period.  I think this is important because its possible to have a closed form solution for speed where the non-closed form elements of distance and non-closed form elements of time cancel out.  However, given that we do have a closed form equation for period, I think that supports your answer.

@CortAmmon Oh, that's a good point. Thanks for mentioning it.
